# Could not connect to New SQL Server in eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse, jdbc, connect

Connecting/pinging a database in eclipse gives me error:

[image: http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/8661/eclipseqf.jpg]

My software is: MySql Server 5.5.12, Connector/J 5.1.17,   Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers v. 1.4.0.20110615-0550.

Logging from console or phpmyadmin works ok.

Here is also screenshot of connection settings:

[image]

Any suggestions about this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading a MSSQL driver, but you are running a MySQL server.

http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: Haven't seen any difference, shame on me! I have changed to load MySql driver, but still I got the error, and I noticed eclipse gives choises only for MySql of version 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, and 5.1 - should I use one of these version instead of 5.5?

Comment: It should surely work with Connector/J 5.1, perhaps the driver is not loaded correctly. (I myself am using Netbeans)

Comment: Ok, you're right, I've connected finally! For some reason the database name doesn't changed in connection url, but only in the text edit field in eclipse. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

change the driver to Mysql driver 5.0 and it will connect properly

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you haven't noticed the question is 8 mounth old :) There's lots of new questions created everyday (second!) on stackowerflow, try answering these instead.